# (Error): ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i tried to create new procedure in oracle.. It raised this error. Please Kindly help

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABS_COLSE(VCOLS VARCHAR2,VTABS VARCHAR2) AS
    STMT VARCHAR2(400);
    TYPE VTYPES IS VARRAY(250) OF VARCHAR2(250);
    RESULTS  VTYPES;
BEGIN
    STMT := 'SELECT '||VCOLS ||' FROM '||VTABS;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(STMT);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STMT BULK COLLECT INTO RESULTS; 
    FOR J IN 1..RESULTS.COUNT() LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULTS(J));
    END LOOP; 
END TABS_COLSE;
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when you CREATE the procedure? Not when you CALL it, after it is created?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like whatever you are passing in as "VTABS" does not exist in the right schema. Nothing wrong with the procedure itself, it compiled fine on my system.

NOTE: Perhaps this was in your original code, or perhaps it was inadvertently changed with the (MUCH NEEDED) edits for formatting, but:

in the FOR loop, you now have 1..RESULTS.COUNT()

That should be RESULTS1  as everywhere else  (the "1" after RESULTS is missing).
I can't edit it for you (edits require at least SIX characters to be changed).